# How do stats work?

Tags: pokemon-series

What are all of the basic stats of my Pokémon and what do they mean?

Please specify if an item is version specific (e.g. not present in Pokémon Blue but perhaps is present in Diamond).

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52075/how-do-i-know-who-attacks-first) covers the Speed stat.

Comment: @STrixVaria so I should ask a seperate question for each of IV EV and Nature? What other stats?

Comment: The basic stats are Attack, Defense, Special Attack, Special Defense, Speed, and HP. I think all those are safe under a single question. Each other category is fairly large and could do with its own question, however. I for one don't mind a little question spam if it makes the information more accessible.

Comment: @StrixVaria are there any other catagories beyond the 3 I mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: Not that I can think of this minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shown traits

Attack - Increases damage done by physical attacks.

Defense - Amount of damage reduction from physical attacks.

Special Attack - Increases damage done by special attacks.

Special defense - Amount of damage reduction from special attacks.

What determines whether a move is [physical](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Physical_move) or [special](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Special_move) changed in generation IV. Before Generation IV this was determined by the type of move. For example, both wing attack and gust are flying. Both are also marked as physical because of this. In generations IV and V however, moves are marked physical or special based on the move itself, not its type. This makes more sense now that gust is special and wing attack would be physical.

Speed - The pokemon with the highest speed takes the first turn in a battle

HP - Your pokemon's total hit points, the amount of damage it can take before fainting.

[Nature](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature) is something you can see and affects all stats depending on which nature a Pokemon has

[EV's or Effort Values](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EV) is a hidden vlaue that also affects Pokemon's stats. There's so much on this topic so it's better to just read the Bulbapedia page for yourself.

[IV's or Individual Values](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/IV) are only used by the game to determine the stats of the Pokemon (e.g. when given an egg, found in the wild, or given by an NPC). IV's also determine whether the Pokemon is shiny or not in every generation other than the first.

The only hidden stats are Accurracy and Evasion. Both are [explained here with mathematic formulas](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats#Formula_for_accuracy_and_evasion)

Comment: You're missing IVs, EVs, and Natures, at the very least.

Comment: Also IV's EV's and nature all _affect_ stats but I'm not sure that's what the OP wanted to know about.

Comment: Down vote because..?

Comment: Also, Special wasn't split in the first generation.

Comment: Just so we are clear, special attacks ONLY take into consideration the Spc Atk and Spc Def of the fighting pokemon, it's not some combination of the non-special and special stats?

Comment: @Ender Correct. If you use Ice Beam, then the opponent's Defense is completely meaningless. Only their Special Defense will be used in the damage calculation.

Comment: IVs are only connected to shininess in Gen II. In Gen III and IV, they sometimes correlate to some degree because of how the RNG works, but in Gen V and later, they're entirely seperate.